# Can we save id() of a variable in a file(filename2.txt), and access that id() from another file(2.py) and access the data in address using ctypes.?

Tags: python-2.7, io, ctypes

```
1.py

import ctypes

filename="sample1.txt"
filename2="sample2.txt"
fo=open(filename,'r+')
str1= fo.read(20)
fo.close()
value_address=id(str1)
ob_rec=ctypes.c_long.from_address(value_address)
print ob_rec
fo1=open(filename2,"wb")
td=str(value_address)
fo1.write(td)
fo1.close()

2.py
import ctypes

filename2="sample2.txt"
fo=open(filename2,'r+')
str1= fo.read(20)
fo.close()
value_address=int(str1)
ob_rec=ctypes.c_long.from_address(value_address)
print ob_rec

sample1.txt
666
```

Here I am getting address in 1.py file for value in sample1.txt and saving it in sample2.txt. But when I am trying the access that address from 2.py,getting getting segmentation fault. Though I am able to access in 1.py successfully.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you open `filename` twice?

Comment: @Alex Sorry..My bad. I edited it. I hope now it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you have two Python processes the virtual address used by CPython for `id()` is not valid in another process.